# Load data from Excel file with a data validation list to SQL Server Database using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, etl

I have an Excel file with a drop down list that I can choose data to display. I want to use SSIS to load the data into my SQL Server Database.

There is around 55 items in the list to choose from so I don't think I want to manually copy paste data from each selection into a new sheet or file.

I did some research but I didn't find any answer on this topic. I'm hoping a script task can do it?

Any idea will help.

Comment: what is the current source of the list? Try importing that.

Comment: source of the list is a bridge table, referencing bunch of other tables, and the content of the underlying data is also made of bunch of formula that reference to different tables. and those table are hidden from me